# Magento get all product attribute from report collection without load

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)     
                 ->addPriceData() 
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->setOrder("ordered_qty", "desc")
                ->setStore($store)
                ->addStoreFilter($store);
```

I used this product collection but when I use foreach for this collection I can not fetch all product attributes like(`small_image`).I know one solution in foreach `$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());` But I do not want to use load in foreach loop. Any alternative soltution ?

Comment: have my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)     
                ->addPriceData() 
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->setOrder("ordered_qty", "desc")
                ->setStore($store)
                ->addStoreFilter($store);

$productIds = $products->getColumnValues('entity_id');

$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','description','price','small_image')) // add whatever product attributes you want
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $productIds));

foreach($productsCollection as $product){
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getDescription();
    echo $product->getPrice();
    echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'small_image');
}
```

Comment: Yes helped,without using product collection possible in report collection ? because product collection and report collection same class extend for addAttributeToSelect() method so.

Comment: Problem is all products list not order_qty descending order in page

Comment: Hello Pradeep are u there

Comment: yes say........ ?

Comment: one confusion.without using product collection possible in report collection ? because product collection and report collection same class extend for addAttributeToSelect() method so

Comment: you mean without using Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') ? and you need bestseller ?

Comment: No ,means that Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') use addAttributeToSelect() and Mage::getModel('catalog/product)'->getCollection() also use addAttributeToSelect()  so addAttributeToSelect() method's class extend in report collection class and prdocut collection class  so why report collection not fetch other product attributes ?

Comment: no that is not possible. because products all attributes cannot be captured at the report level.only master data like entity id and sku will be captured in the report module

Comment: Just as a note here, the method getcolumnValues includes a load of the collection, so you are still loading it with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find any fast solution within reasonable time. So I am accessing the DB almost directly.
load($productId, array($attributeCode)) loads all the product information
For other solutions I run out of memory on my local machine.

```
/*
  get product attribute integer value
*/
function getProductAttributeInt($productId, $attributeCode){
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    return  
      $readConnection->fetchOne(
        'select value from catalog_product_entity_int where entity_id=' . $productId . '
         and attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = \'' . $attributeCode . '\')'
      );
}
```